# Windows IoT, IoT Hub, Stream Analytics, Azure SQL, Power BI - What is the right path?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm working on a IoT Proof of Concept where i through an IoT device collect information which I want to  process in Azure.

Simplified I have 2 tables:

**UserTable**

- UserID (collected from NFC reading on the device at first time use)
- Name (written by user on the touchscreen)
- E-mail

**MagicTable**

- UserID (collected from NFC reading on the device when user scans his
  card)
- Data 1
- Data 2

MagicTable will be subject for analysis and some AI/prediction.

My device is connected and send data through IoT Hub. I have tested to send MagicTable the path IoTHub => StreamAnalytics => PowerBI and it works flawless, but I need to attach the UserTable for joining the UserID. My logic says that a usertable has nothing to do in Stream Analytics. Should I use an simple Azure SQL table. Where do I do the join?

My first goal is to present data in PowerBI (where Names are associated with data from MagicTable).

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption about not using Stream Analytics for reference data joins is wrong. You can do the join in Azure Stream Analytics. For that to work the reference data should be slow in changes. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-use-reference-data)

> Reference data (also known as a lookup table) is a finite data set that is static or slowing changing in nature, used to perform a lookup or to correlate with your data stream...

There are some requirements when it comes to the reference data though, so you should make sure it applies to your situation:

> Stream Analytics uses Azure Blob storage as the storage layer for Reference Data, and with Azure Data Factory reference data can be transformed and/or copied to Azure Blob storage, for use as Reference Data, from any number of cloud-based and on-premises data stores. Reference data is modeled as a sequence of blobs (defined in the input configuration) in ascending order of the date/time specified in the blob name. It only supports adding to the end of the sequence by using a date/time greater than the one specified by the last blob in the sequence.

If you cannot use this you have to join the data using a separate process. You can read the IoT hub data using an azure function for example, join with the reference data there and output in to another event hub -> stream analytics -> power bi.